# Google Play Console: Exclude all non-tablet devices (without manipulating manifest.xml)

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have an App on Google Play Console. Now I want to restrict the target devices to "only tablets".

Currently I do:

- go to play console
- choose my app
- on the left chose: "Device catalog"
- "Add filter" -> Form Factor -> 'chose everything except for tablet'
- select all devices that were found after applying the filter (maximum 500 per page)
- click on "manage devices" -> exclude devices

However, I can exclude only 500 devices (that are loaded per page) at once. I have ~10000 devices in total. So I need to repeat this 20 times to exclude them all (and the same if you want to revert the changes).

Does anyone know how to deal with that?

Disclaimer: I found similar questions on StackOverflow, but I'm particularly looking for a solution that does not involve "manipulating manifest.xml". I want to do this dynamically without having to re-build my app

**Edit**
Meanwhile I tried injecting a small javascript function into the Website. This time I want to filter devices with Mali GPUs. Unfortunately it's not working. However, the right finds all the right rows to check, only the "ckeck-in" operation seems not to work:

```
// Get all div elements with the class 'particle-table-row'
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.particle-table-row');

// Loop through all rows
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  // Get the row and its text
  var row = rows[i];
  var text = row.textContent;

  // Check if the text contains the string "Mali" and the row is not already selected
  if(text.includes('Mali') && !row.classList.contains('particle-row-selected')) {
    // Get the checkbox within the row
    var checkbox = row.querySelector('mat-checkbox');

    // If the checkbox exists, check it
    if (checkbox) {
        checkbox.click();  // clicking the checkbox as setting checked property might not trigger events
        checkedCounter++;
    }
  }
}
```

will post an update once I found the problem

Comment: FYI: Mali is used in Tablets - just as you said you wanted to filter for Tablets, but your example code is removing Mali.